# What is the canonical url of my website with www or without?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

For my site: http://www.indiacustomercare.com  which one is the canonical url with www or without www?
I've not changed any settings.
I remember that I changed this to www. in one for my previous drupal-6 website but I've forgotten it now(I did not change .htaccess).

So if I access my site as http://indiacustomercare.com then all pages seem to be without www ( except for those in the footer which are hardcoded with www...)
Similarly for when I access my site as http://www.indiacustomercare.com all web pages seem to have www prefix.

So what is my site's default www or without www?

Comment: [It depends](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_normalization#Semantic_changing_normalizations).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in Drupal .htaccess there are pre-defined settings for this. Go to line 90-97, choose which domain you want to use (with or without www), uncomment the appropriate lines and add there your domain.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This one redirects from example.com to www.example.com.
There is also the opposite direction below.

Answer (score 1):

You choose, but it's considered best practice to go with either one or the other, and not leave both available. If you set up a [301 Redirect](http://www.webconfs.com/how-to-redirect-a-webpage.php), it is nicer for search engines.

Comment: What do you mean by "leave both available". In google webmaster tools, we can choose to go by default and let Google choose the appropriate. Also this 301 you've talked about -- isn't it to be done in the .htaccess by uncommenting a couple of lines?

Comment: Hopefully, it's not just Google that will be visiting your website; it's possible that Yahoo or Bing could index your site and get your links differently? It's better to set up the redirect on your server instead of relying on other services to know how you want your site set up. Regarding the 301, you are correct: it is best done in the .htaccess file. The link I provided was for all the options you had, rather than Drupal-specific.